# Cmake error log while trying to compile aseprite

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, sprite

So I’m trying to compile aseprite on Windows, I’ve installed and extracted the newest version of all the necessary stuff following this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=si7N0GeqOH8 and, of course, this one https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/master/INSTALL.md 1. But when I try running the cmake line:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DLAF_BACKEND=skia -DSKIA_DIR=C:\deps\skia -DSKIA_LIBRARY_DIR=C:\deps\skia\tools\out\Release-x64 -DSKIA_DIR=C:\deps\skia -DSKIA_OUT_DIR=C:\deps\skia\out\Release-x64 -G Ninja ..
```

It outputs a long error message:

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:16 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0046 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE2 - Success
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE41
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_SSE41 - Success
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_AVX2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_AVX2 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_AVX2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_AVX2 - Success
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS32 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MIPS_DSP_R2 - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_NEON - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA - Failed
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA
-- Performing Test WEBP_HAVE_FLAG_MSA - Failed
-- curl version=[7.21.6]
-- LDAP_H not found CURL_DISABLE_LDAP set ON
CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:562 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "HAVE_FCNTL_O_NONBLOCK" will no longer be
  dereferenced when the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set
  the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:664 (curl_internal_test)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:594 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "HAVE_GLIBC_STRERROR_R_COMPILE" will no longer be
  dereferenced when the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set
  the OLD behavior will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:673 (curl_internal_test_run)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMake/CurlCheckCSourceCompiles.cmake:16 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "curl_cv_recv" will no longer be dereferenced when
  the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior
  will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/curl/CMake/OtherTests.cmake:31 (curl_check_c_source_compiles)
  third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:792 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at third_party/curl/CMake/CurlCheckCSourceRuns.cmake:16 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.

  Quoted variables like "HAVE_POLL_FINE" will no longer be dereferenced when
  the policy is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior
  will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/curl/CMake/OtherTests.cmake:202 (curl_check_c_source_runs)
  third_party/curl/CMakeLists.txt:792 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:272 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PkgConfig)
  does not match the name of the calling package (HarfBuzz).  This can lead
  to problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:45 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/FindHarfBuzz.cmake:33 (include)
  third_party/freetype2/CMakeLists.txt:191 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
-- Could NOT find BZip2 (missing: BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Building introspection files on Windows requires BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to be enabled.
-- Version: 6.1.0
-- Build type: RelWithDebInfo
-- CXX_STANDARD: 11
CMake Deprecation Warning at third_party/cmark/CMakeLists.txt:6 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0048 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- Could NOT find LIBB2 (missing: LIBB2_LIBRARY LIBB2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find LZ4 (missing: LZ4_LIBRARY LZ4_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find ZSTD (missing: ZSTD_LIBRARY ZSTD_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:272 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (NETTLE)
  does not match the name of the calling package (Nettle).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/libarchive/build/cmake/FindNettle.cmake:19 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  third_party/libarchive/CMakeLists.txt:752 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find NETTLE (missing: NETTLE_LIBRARY NETTLE_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenSSL, try to set the path to OpenSSL root folder in the system variable OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR (missing: OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find EXPAT (missing: EXPAT_LIBRARY EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:272 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (LIBGCC)
  does not match the name of the calling package (LibGCC).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/libarchive/build/cmake/FindLibGCC.cmake:17 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  third_party/libarchive/CMakeLists.txt:1227 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find LIBGCC (missing: LIBGCC_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find PCREPOSIX (missing: PCREPOSIX_LIBRARY PCRE_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:272 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PCRE) does
  not match the name of the calling package (PCREPOSIX).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  third_party/libarchive/build/cmake/FindPCREPOSIX.cmake:23 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  third_party/libarchive/CMakeLists.txt:1232 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Could NOT find PCRE (missing: PCRE_LIBRARY)
-- Extended attributes support: none
-- ACL support: none
-- laf backend: skia
-- laf pixman: pixman
-- laf freetype: freetype
-- laf harfbuzz: harfbuzz
-- skia dir: C:/Aseprite/build/%SKIA%
-- skia library: SKIA_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- skia library dir: C:/deps/skia/tools/out/Release-x64
CMake Error at laf/CMakeLists.txt:84 (message):
  set SKIA_DIR/SKIA_LIBRARY/SKIA_LIBRARY_DIR to compile w/skia backend


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Aseprite/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I tried checking the logs they provided but I couldn't understand anything (I also don't know if trying to build it on linux is easier tho). I can show the files if necessary but I don’t know what to do from here, help…

Answer (score 0):

type winver in cmd
then you need to install the correct windows sdk version & delete version above your winver
try again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).